# Paypal MECL Support Date

Tags: android, paypal

Looking at the Mobile Express Checkout Library from Paypal, particularly with respect to Android, does anyone know if there is a stated support date? Info can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout-library/), but it also states [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions) that the MECL library has been discontinued.

I was wondering if anyone knows how long the discontinued libraries will still function? Is there any planned end of life or ballpark time frame to switch entirely to the APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that the first link is a bit confusing. The page, in spite of the title, discusses Mobile Express Checkout and not the Mobile Express Checkout Libary (MECL).

The MECL, as indicated in the second link, has been discontinued and is no longer supported. You should instead be using MEC or the new Mobile SDK depending on where you are located and your needs.